# show/hide will not load

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking the "see more" the text does not expand. How come? Thanks

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrap">
      <h1>Show/Hide Content</h1>
      <p>
          This example shows you how to create a show/hide container using a 
          couple of links, a div, a few lines of CSS, and some JavaScript to 
          manipulate our CSS. Just click on the "see more" link at the end of 
          this paragraph to see the technique in action, and be sure to view the 
          source to see how it all works together. 
          <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink"
              onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
              See more.
          </a>
      </p>
      <div id="example" class="more">
         <p>
             Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the 
             link below will hide this content again.
         </p>
         <p>
             <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink"
                 onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
                 Hide this content.
             </a>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>​
```

**Javascript**:

```
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID).style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
   }
}
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    background-color: #777; 
}
#wrap {
    font: 1.3em/1.3 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 30em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #fff; 
}
h1 {
    font-size: 200%; 
}
/* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */
.more {
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
}
a.showLink, a.hideLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #36f;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; 
}
a.hideLink {
    background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; 
}
a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; 
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EMEL6/)

Comment: Please include your code within the question. If jsfiddle goes down your question will be worthless to others in the future. Also please put a more thorough description of what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected a small bug that it needs 2 clicks to start the functioning. Just replaced != 'none' has been replaced with  == 'block'. Also, in JSFiddle, you had chosen wrong setting under the 'choose framework'. It should have been 'head no wrap'.

http://jsfiddle.net/EMEL6/12/

Also a very simple way to achieve the same:

```
function showHide() {
    $('#example').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `showHide` from the HTML window, but `showHide` hasn't been defined yet.  Just include the `showHide` function in a `<script>` block in the HTML window, and it will work.  See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HGbSX/1/

The additional problem with having to click twice to show the additional content has to do with your logic.  The first time you come through, the display for that element is not set to `none` as you expect, but to an empty string, so it's re-hiding it.  You can correct this by reversing your logic, and looking for `display='block'`.  See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HGbSX/2/

Comment: can you try jquery <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showLink").click(function(){
    $(".more").toggle();
  });
});
</script>

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to save.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I am having a problem where the "see more" has to be clicked twice to be shown.. any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/HGbSX/1/

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct; the reason it is not working is because the way you have the jsfiddle set up. On the right side where it asks for a framework/where you want your JS to show up, you have jQuery and onLoad (the defaults, I believe) - this makes it so that the resulting code of your fiddle looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID).style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
   }
}

});//]]>
```

Which means you are defining showHide within the anonymous function of jQuery's load event. If you change the first dropdown to 'no wrap (head)' it will leave your JavaScript alone and your onclick will be able to see the function as defined.

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you know why the "see more" has to be clicked twice to show?